# Generating random numbers that average to a specified value

Tags: r

So in R, I want to generate a small set of random numbers that average to a pre-specified number. For instance, given value X, I want to generate random numbers that when averaged return the value X. I would like the generated numbers to follow a normal distribution.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of precision are you looking for when you say "average to a pre-specified number"? For example, `rnorm(n,pre_specified_number,non_zero_sigma)` will be normally distributed with an average approximately equal to `pre_specified_number` for sufficiently large `n` and/or sufficiently small `non_zero_sigma`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your question looks fine to me, and asking a good question on your first attempt is difficult, so good job!  You may want to take a look at the site tour on help --> site tour, you learn more about the site, and get a badge for doing it!

Comment: @nrussell - I want precision, but I also want some variance associated with the generated numbers. The scale option below allows me to get variability in the generated numbers while also achieving precision.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To sample from the normal distribution, use `rnorm()`

```
# Sample from normal distribution with mean=3
x <- rnorm(5, mean=3, sd=2)

mean(x)
[1] 2.867709
```

Note that your actual mean is different from the desired mean, due to your very small sample.  You can use `scale()` to adjust this:

```
# Scale with mean=0, then add the desired mean
z <- 3 + scale(x, center = TRUE, scale=FALSE)

mean(z)
[1] 3
```